# Java Integer addition

Tags: java, integer, addition

my program has the user enter some 5 digit number, I need a way to take that 5 digit integer and add all the digits together. For example, the user enters 26506, the program does 2+6+5+0+6 and returns 19. I believe this would be done by some sort of loop but am unsure of where to start.

For clarification, this integer could be anything, just has to be 5 digits.

Comment: You need `modulus (%)` operator. Google it.

Comment: doesnt modulus take the remainder though?

Comment: Exactly why you need it.

Comment: If you do a modulus of a number with 10, you will get the last digit as remainder. Makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

From the top of my head, you can convert it to string and iterate over each char, accumulating the value with ( charAt( position ) - '0' ). I'm away from a java compiler right now, but I guess this should work. Just make sure you have numerical data only.

Comment: From what I get, it seems I'm the only one with this solution in mind...Is this wrong?

Comment: It's a clumsy, inelegant solution.

Comment: I will think about it. Thank you, @Hot Licks, for bothering to answer. But, OTOH, isn't % kind of expensive against my solution? Just thinking ( but still, faster almost always tend to be inelegant ).

Comment: Converting an int to a string involves repeated application of `%` to develop the digits.  Plus you pay to allocate the string object, which is 100 times more expensive than the `%` operations.

Comment: I'm aware the question was closed, but I was thinking: Since the user enters interactively the data, isn't it already a previously allocated string? That would actually make my solution at least as optimal as the (slick and elegant) solution given by @Md. Taufique Hussain.

Comment: We have no indication as to HOW the number is entered, or how many thousands of lines earlier that occurred.  And it wasn't the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

```
int sum = 0;
while(input > 0){
    sum += input % 10;
    input = input / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each time you take a `modulus` of a number by `10`, you get digits at `ones` place. And each time to `divide` your number by 10, you get all the digits except the `ones` digit. So you can use this approach to sum all your digits like this: -

```
22034 % 10 = 4
22034 / 10 = 2203

2203 % 10 = 3
2203 / 10 = 220

220 % 10 = 0
220 / 10 = 22

22 % 10 = 2
22 / 10 = 2

2 % 10 = 2
```

Add all of them.. (4 + 3 + 0 + 2 + 2 = 11)

Comment: Nice for providing the algorithm and not the code

Comment: @SteveKuo Yeah. That is the best way we can help `beginners`. Not by providing straight code. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide and take the modulus:

```
26506 / 10000 = 2
26506 % 10000 = 6506

6506 / 1000 = 6
6506 % 1000 = 506

506 / 100 = 5
506 % 100 = 6

6 / 10 = 0
6 % 10 = 6

6 / 1 = 6
```

So the result of each division is the digit for that base10 place, in order to get the next lesser significant digit, you take the modulus. Then repeat.

Comment: @JonLin.. I think you should go the other way round. Take the once digit then tens digit and so on. That way you just need to use `10` in denominator.. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

If  your input is in String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Enter your number: ");


        try{
            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = bufferRead.readLine();
            char[] tokens;
            tokens = input.toCharArray();
            int total=0;
            for(char i : tokens){
                total += Character.getNumericValue(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Total: " + total);

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
    }
```

If your input is in Integers, simple use

```
    String stringValue = Integer.toString(integerValue);
```

and plug it in.

Comment: +1 for getNumericValue and direct processing of the string

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

UNPACK the number using:(assuming the number remains 5 characters)

```
int unpack(int number)
{
    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        x += number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return x;
}
```

put it into a string and select individual characters and parse into
    Integer:

```
int sumWithString(String s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0;j < 5;j++){
        try{
        sum += Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(j));
        }catch(Exception e){ }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    String s = scanner.nextLine();

    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    int total = 0;

    for(char x: a){
        try {
            total += Integer.parseInt(""+x);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    System.out.println(total);
```

This will omit any non-number character.