# Java Integer digit reader

Tags: java, digit

I am creating a method that needs to read a 5 digit integer digit by digit. (ie 26505 would be read as 2 6 5 0 5, and each digit could be read individually in another method) I cannot convert the integer to a string and read each character because I need the digits to be read by another method. It has also been suggested to use %10 but that wouldnt give me individual digits. Also, the integer needs to be read digit by digit from the left to right. I hope this is clear enough, but I am really confused on how to complete this and everything I have tried does not work. Any help offered would be appreciated, thank you.

```
    while(d>=10){  
    j=code%d;
    d=d/10;
    printDigit(j)
```

Comment: Why not convert to String and use the resulting digits found to be read by another method? It's not like once you convert them they're destroyed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, "It has also been suggested to use %10 but that wouldnt give me individual digits." How will that not give you individual digits?

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you show us what code you've got?

Comment: Your question is a subset of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922377/java-integer-addition which you asked yesterday. The answers there apply here.

Comment: @SteveKuo Oh Dear. Didn't even noticed that. :-\

Answer (score 3):

For getting single digits from **left-to-right**: -

```
26505 / 10000 = 2
26505 % 10000 = 6505

6505 / 1000 = 6
6505 % 1000 = 505

505 / 100 = 5
505 % 100 = 5

5 / 10 = 5
```

I think you can now implement it.

But, if you are OK with **traversing from right-to-left**, it would be easier, since then your denominator will be fixed to 10: -

```
26505 % 10 = 5
26505 / 10 = 2650

2650 % 10 = 0
2650 / 10 = 265

265 % 10 = 5
265 / 10 = 26

26 % 10 = 6
26 / 10 = 2

2 % 10 = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return an array with the integer digits in order.

```
public static int[] integerToDigits(int n)
{
    int[] digits= new int[5];
    int temp = n;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        digits[4-i] = temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

`integerToDigits(12345) = {1,2,3,4,5}`

Answer (score 0):

Something totally lazy would look like

```
final int [] digits = {score % 1000 / 100, score % 100 / 10, score % 10};
```

which would work if you know your ints will never be larger than 999, for example.

From this example, it is trivial to improve it to support arbitrary integers by calculating the next power of ten from your integer and then adding digits to the array in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. you can create a integer array and parse the each character of the user input string into and store into an array
2. then you can use this array for your other method.

e.g.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    int[] digitArray = new int[str.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        String temp = Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
        System.out.println("temp is "+temp);
        digitArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    }
    for (int i =0; i<digitArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(digitArray[i]);
    }
```